# Prefix css selectors for make styles from API safe

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, css-modules, react-css-modules

Let's assume that the user can add styles for every component in admin panel and I get it as string in my Node server:

```
const stylesFromAPI = ".p { color: red } .bg { background: lime }";
```

How to prefix this styles before append to my document to avoid conflicts?
I need something like CSS modules but working with strings (not as module loader):

```
const stylesFromAPI = css(".p { color: red } .bg { background: lime }"); // returns hashedClassname685946898456
<SomeCompontent className={stylesFromAPI} />
```

produces:

```
<style>
  .hashedClassname685946898456 .p { color: red }
  .hashedClassname685946898456 .bg { background: lime }
</style>
<div class="hashedClassname685946898456"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shadow DOM seems like a reasonable option here. You can create your style tags with inside the shadow DOM without having to deal with any selector prefixes. For example, using the [react-shadow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-shadow) package:

```
import root from 'react-shadow';
```

Then in JSX, something like:

```
<root.div>
    <style type="text/css">
        {/* CSS string here */}
    </style>
    <div>
        {/* Stuff here */}
    </div>
</root.div>
```

Check out a working example of this here: https://github.com/joshdavenport/stack-overflow-61566764-react-css-shadow-dom

The main downside here is your styles from outside the shadow DOM will not apply. Those using the shadow DOM for components see this as a good thing, those [simply trying to scope CSS do not](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/552). Not sure what it is you're scoping, so I can't really tell if that would be an issue for you.

If it is, you could re-import your styles within the shadow DOM, though I can't really point out how to do that without knowing what bundler is in use and how it is in use.

Alternatively you could pull apart your imported CSS using the [css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css) package, iterate over the selectors prefixing all with a randomly generated class, and then re-[stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css#cssstringifyobject-options).